# Vagrant / Puppet error -Error: Could not find class apt for precise32 on node precise32

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up a complete dev environment using java/maven/tomcat. So far I can run an instance which works fine, I'm now trying to package it all together and encountering problems.

I've tried various things but always getting the same error: `Error: Could not find class apt for precise32 on node precise32`

I've installed various puppet modules on a shared folder thinking that that would help solve as I found a post saying sodlib was required, this is installed in that folder.  I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.  I can ssh in to the vm and confirm that the shared folders are available and that putty is installed.

the vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.33.10'
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 4880
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 4800
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1099, host: 1099
  config.vm.synced_folder "/..path../Vagrant_MASTER/Shared_Resources/artifacts", "/artifacts", create: true

  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "puppet_script.sh"
  #share the puppet folder?
  config.vm.synced_folder  "/..path../Vagrant_MASTER/Shared_Resources/puppet", "/puppet", create:true
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.module_path = "/..path../Vagrant_MASTER/Shared_Resources/puppet/modules" 
    puppet.manifests_path = "/..path../Vagrant_MASTER/Shared_Resources/puppet/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "/..path../Vagrant_MASTER/Shared_Resources/puppet/java-maven-tomcat7.pp"
  end

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end
end
```

the puppet script is a carbon copy from the puppet site.

Thanks for any help.